# How to add high resolution images in a linear layout horizontally in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I want two add images horizontally in a linear layout, but they are of high resolution.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/img1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>;
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/img2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>;
```

Comment: Add android:orientation="horizontal" to linear layout then change ImageView width 0dp and add layoutweight="1" to both, change value as per required. Use android: src="@drawable/img1" to add image from drawable

Answer (score 0):

Use android:orientation atribute

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="top">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:src="@drawable/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:src="@drawable/img2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout >
```

dont forget to add images img1,img2 in drawable folder